# Push Notification lag time

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Do push notifications, https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/push, have the same lag time as querying for login events?

In other words, if I set a push notification for login events, will I wait 1-2 days to receive POST requests from Google?

Comment: Yes. Based from the the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/push#understanding-reports-api-notification-events), because notifications are not 100% reliable, expect a small percentage of messages to get dropped under normal working conditions. Therefore, there's a list for [data retention and lag times](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7061566) that reflect how long it takes before collected data tied to specific Admin console reports and audit logs is available to view.

Comment: I don't understand this feature then. The max timeout time is 6 hours for a given channel so you won't be able to collect any events that occur within the window the channel is active? What's the point?